# How do I disconnect a Wi-Fi network in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: wireless, 17.10, gnome-shell

In Ubuntu 17.10 there is no option to disconnect a Wi-Fi network. I now have to turn off Wi-Fi which will enable airplane mode.

How can I just disconnect from Wi-Fi without entering airplane mode?

Comment: Related question: [Script to disconnect from the actual wifi](https://askubuntu.com/q/1143080/1548713)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try one GNOME shell [extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [Disconnect Wifi](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/904/disconnect-wifi/) to achieve your goal. It

> Adds a Disconnect option for Wifi in status menu, when a network is connected. Shows a Reconnect option, after network is disconnected.

[image]
(screenshot source: extension's homepage at extensions.gnome.org)

Answer (score 1):

In terminal type:

```
nmcli nm enable false
```

To disconnect from all connections using the default Network-Manager. Alternatively:

```
nmcli nm enable true
```

To connect again.

You can also use:

```
nmcli c down id <SSID>
```

and

```
nmcli c up id <SSID>
```

to connect/disconnect from networks.