# script to disconnect from the actual wifi

Tags: 18.04, bash, scripts, ubuntu-dock

There is a way to disconnect my laptop from the wifi connection by pressing an icon on the dock and/or by executing a script?

Thanks

Comment: You can disconnect your wifi with `nmcli radio wifi off`. You can check the status with `nmcli radio wifi`. To enable WiFi `nmcli radio wifi on`.

Comment: You can also disconnect your wifi with `sudo ip link set <device> down`.  To enable `sudo ip link set <device> up`. The <device> name can be obtained with `ip a` command. For example, the <device> is `wlp5s0`.  So give command as `sudo ip link set wlp5s0 down` to turn off Wi-Fi. Similarly the command `sudo ip link set wlp5s0 down` turn on Wi-Fi.

Comment: You can create aliases for `turn-on` as well as for `turn-off` such as `alias WiFiOff='nmcli radio wifi off'`  and `alias WiFiON='nmcli radio wifi on'`. You can also create a desktop shortcut launcher for this command (create sh script and add this command) with any icon of your choice.

Comment: Related question: [How do I disconnect a Wi-Fi network in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/q/973753/1548713)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ## How to Enable/Disable WI-Fi interface Adapter?

## Method-1:

To enable your Wi-Fi, run the following command:

```
$ nmcli radio wifi on
```

To disbale your Wi-Fi, run the following command:

```
$ nmcli radio wifi off
```

To test the status of Wi-Fi whether enabled or not, issue the following command:

```
$ nmcli radio wifi
disabled
```

## Method-2:

There is another way. In order to apply this method, first you need to find out the Wi-Fi device, so issue the following command:

```
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:1b:0d:62:cf:95 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1c:1b:0d:62:cf:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:a4:71:58:d5:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Refer **item-4** in the output which displays the Wi-Fi device `wlp5s0`. Notice that the state of device from output is `state UP` which means that the Wi-Fi is up and running.

To enable Wi-Fi, run the following command:

```
$ sudo ip link set wlp5s0 up
```

To disable Wi-Fi, issue the following command:

```
$ sudo ip link set wlp5s0 down
```

To know the status of Wi-Fi, issue the following command:

```
$ ip link show wlp5s0
4: wlp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:a4:71:58:d5:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

From the above output, one can observe that the state of device is `state DOWN` which means that the Wi-Fi is disabled.

## Turn on and off using aliases.

You can create alias to turn on Wi-Fi as follows:

```
alias wifion='nmcli radio wifi on'
```

Similarly, to turn off create another alias as follows:

```
alias wifioff='nmcli radio wifi off'
```

To check the status of Wi-Fi whether it is diabled or not, create another alias as follows:

```
alias wifi='nmcli radio wifi'
```

## Desktop Shortcut Launcher to turn off Wi-Fi.

Create a file `~/wifi/wifioff.desktop` and copy the following contents into the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=WiFi-Off
Type=Application
Exec=/home/krishna/wifi/wifioff.sh
Icon=/home/krishna/wifi/wifioff.png
Comment=WiFi Off Script
Terminal=true
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Now, run the following command to install shortcut file in `/usr/share/applications/` directory:

```
$ sudo desktop-file-install wifioff.desktop
```

[image]

Now create `~/wifi/wifioff.sh` file having the following command:

```
$ gnome-terminal -e "/bin/bash -c 'nmcli radio wifi off;nmcli radio wifi;$SHELL'"
```

Now make the script file executable by the following command:

```
$ chmod +x ~/wifi/wifioff.sh
```

You may [download a suitable icon](https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=arrow) file.

[image]

The `~/wifi/wifioff.png` file represents as the icon of the desktop launcher `wifioff.desktop`.

If you click icon `WiFi-Off` on Dash, then your Wi-Fi interface will be disabled and you will also see message `Disabled` displayed on the command terminal.

## Desktop Shortcut Launcher to turn on Wi-Fi.

You can also install another `Desktop Shortcut Launcher` to turn on Wi-Fi. You need three files similar to `Wi-Fi Off` which are wifion.desktop, wifion.sh and wifion.png respectively.

Create a file `~/wifi/wifion.desktop` and copy the following contents into the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=WiFi-On
Type=Application
Exec=/home/krishna/wifi/wifion.sh
Icon=/home/krishna/wifi/wifion.png
Comment=WiFi On Script
Terminal=true
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Now, run the following command to install shortcut file in `/usr/share/applications/` directory:

```
$ sudo desktop-file-install wifion.desktop
```

[image]

Now create `~/wifi/wifion.sh` file having the following command:

```
$ gnome-terminal -e "/bin/bash -c 'nmcli radio wifi on;nmcli radio wifi;$SHELL'"
```

Now make the script file executable by the following command:

```
$ chmod +x ~/wifi/wifion.sh
```

You may [download a suitable icon](https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=arrow) file.

[image]

The `~/wifi/wifion.png` file represents as the icon of the desktop launcher `wifion.desktop`.

If you click icon `WiFi-On` on Dash, then your Wi-Fi interface will be enabled and you will also see message `Enabled` displayed on the command terminal.

## Desktop Shortcut Launcher to display Enable/Disable Status of Wi-Fi.

You can also install a third `Desktop Shortcut Launcher` to find out the status of Wi-Fi whether it is enabled or not. To accomplish this, just follow the procedure.

Create a file `~/wifi/wifistatus.desktop` and copy the following contents into the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=WiFi-Status
Type=Application
Exec=/home/krishna/wifi/wifistatus.sh
Icon=/home/krishna/wifi/wifistatus.png
Comment=WiFi Status On Script
Terminal=true
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Now, run the following command to install shortcut file in `/usr/share/applications/` directory:

```
$ sudo desktop-file-install wifistatus.desktop
```

[image]

Now create `~/wifi/wifistatus.sh` file having the following command:

```
$ gnome-terminal -e "/bin/bash -c 'nmcli radio wifi;$SHELL'"
```

Now make the script file executable by the following command:

```
$ chmod +x ~/wifi/wifistatus.sh
```

You may [download a suitable icon](https://www.flaticon.com/free-icons/alphabet) file.

The `~/wifi/wifistatus.png` file represents as the icon of the desktop launcher `wifistatus.desktop`.

If you click icon `WiFi-Status` on Dash, then the status of your Wi-Fi interface will be displayed either as `Enabled` or `Disabled` on the command terminal.

## Desktop Shortcut Launchers for Wi-Fi on Dash.

Dash displays the presence of all three icons regarding Wi-Fi installed on the system as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension to do what you want as described in [Ubuntu Handbook](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/08/add-disconnect-wifi-option-ubuntu-18-04/). Open `Ubuntu Software` and enter `Disconnect WiFi`

After installation you can disconnect with image on left and reconnect with image on right:

[image: Wifi Disconnect.png]

Answer (score 0):

The following command should work:

```
nmcli device disconnect wlo1
```

where *wlo1* is your WIFI device. You can get the network device names using:

```
ip a
```

or just

```
nmcli
```